# Start to/of the day

Tags: prepositions

Can we use

> A perfect start **to** a day

or

> A perfect start **of** the day

Please explain me properly

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, "a perfect start of the day" makes sense. And without the word "perfect", it would usually be the best choice, as in "at the start of the day".

But there is an established idiom for phrases like "a good start to" when describing some period of time or event, where the adjective *good* can be replaced with many other adjectives describing value quality: *great*, *perfect*, *excellent*, *bad*, *poor*, *disappointing*, etc.

Since probably most English speakers are used to this idiom, it will be better to say "a perfect start to the day".

(Interestingly, it looks a century or more ago, "a good start of" was more common than "a good start to", but "a good start to" has been steadily becoming more frequent: [see the Google ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good%20start%20to%2Cgood%20start%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share&).)

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference in emphasis:

**Start of the Day**: This phrase emphasizes the very beginning of the day, right when a new day begins, often associated with midnight or early morning. It's about marking the transition from one day to the next on the calendar.

Example: "*I like to wake up at the start of the day to watch the sunrise.*"

**Start to the Day**: This phrase emphasizes the early hours and activities that set the tone for the rest of the day. It's about the initial phase of the day, encompassing morning routines, breakfast, and the first tasks or events after waking up.

Example: "*A healthy breakfast is essential for a good start to the day.*"